# How do I close a kivy application window with a button press?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I am making a snake game in Python using Pygame and I want to add a Menu screen using the Kivy Framework. I have a "play" button in the center, and when I click it I want to close the kivy window but not Python Program as I want the game to run after you click the button.

I have already tried using `app.stop()` but that only clears the kivy window and and the windows sits there covering the screen.

Comment: What is the command used to start the snake game?

Comment: I have used a `main()` function to start the playable part of the game. earlier i called the main() function using `if __name__ == "__main__":`

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind `on_request_close` to a function that calls `Window.close()` (among other exit scripts).

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class GameApp(App):
       
    def build(self):
        return MenuScreen()

class MenuScreen(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MenuScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)   
        Window.bind(on_request_close=self.end_func)

    def end_func(self, *args):
        app.stop()
        Window.close()
```

Comment: This closed the app for me but I can't start a new one, for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    App.stop
    Window.close()
```

***This worked out for me***

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).